# Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetExists($key) error in WP 6 and PHP 8.1

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, php-8.1

We are upgrading a WordPress app with ACF Pro to PHP 8.1 and we encounter an error in `Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetExists($key)`

```
Fatal error: During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php(15): errorHandler(8192, 'Return type of ...', '/var/www/html/w...', 63)
#1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-requests.php(146): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#2 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-requests.php(591): Requests::autoloader('Requests_Cookie...')
#3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-requests.php(365): Requests::set_defaults('https://www.you...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-http.php(395): Requests::request('https://www.you...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-http.php(633): WP_Http->request('https://www.you...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/wp-includes/http.php(68): WP_Http->get('https://www.you...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php(450): wp_safe_remote_get('https://www.you...', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php(281): WP_oEmbed->discover('https://www.you...')
#9 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php(351): WP_oEmbed->get_provider('https://www.you...', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php(404): WP_oEmbed->get_data('https://www.you...', Array)
#11 /var/www/html/wp-includes/embed.php(115): WP_oEmbed->get_html('https://www.you...', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/fields/class-acf-field-oembed.php(93): wp_oembed_get('https://www.you...', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/fields/class-acf-field-oembed.php(327): acf_field_oembed->wp_oembed_get('https://www.you...', 521, 346)
#14 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): acf_field_oembed->format_value('https://www.you...', 'options', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(256): WP_Hook->apply_filters('https://www.you...', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/acf-hook-functions.php(109): apply_filters_ref_array('acf/format_valu...', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): _acf_apply_hook_variations('https://www.you...', 'options', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('https://www.you...', Array)
#19 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/acf-value-functions.php(172): apply_filters('acf/format_valu...', 'https://www.you...', 'options', Array)
#20 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/fields/class-acf-field-group.php(147): acf_format_value('https://www.you...', 'options', Array)
#21 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): acf_field__group->format_value(Array, 'options', Array)
#22 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(256): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/acf-hook-functions.php(109): apply_filters_ref_array('acf/format_valu...', Array)
#24 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): _acf_apply_hook_variations(Array, 'options', Array)
#25 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/acf-value-functions.php(172): apply_filters('acf/format_valu...', Array, 'options', Array)
#27 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/api/api-template.php(321): acf_format_value(Array, 'options', Array)
#28 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/api/api-template.php(243): get_field_objects('options', true)
#29 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/business/index.php(4): get_fields('option')
#30 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/index.php(4): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#31 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php(232): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#32 /var/www/html/wp-settings.php(585): include('/var/www/html/w...')
#33 /var/www/html/wp-config.php(133): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#34 /var/www/html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#35 /var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#36 /var/www/html/index.php(17): require('/var/www/html/w...')
#37 {main} in /var/www/html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 15
```